# QGIS Processing Toolbox removed Scripts

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I was working with adding a new script to toolbox in QGIS but the script wouldn't show up there. Then when I tried again the Scripts tool has disappeared altogether. I have checked in settings and it does not give the option to add the scripts back in. I have attached some screenshots as an example. Has anyone experienced this before and know why it might occur? I have tried reinstalling and resetting to defaults but still have not had any luck.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's poor design/a bug with QGIS processing scripts.  If you save a broken script, e.g. one that has a `SyntaxError`, none of the scripts will get loaded and the whole scripts toolbox disappears.

Either:

- Use the Scripts menu to open the broken script and fix it,
  [image]

Or:

- Go to your profile folder:

  [image]

  Open the "processing/scripts" folder and find the script you were working on so you can fix it.

  [image]

How you fix it depends on what the problem is, but I recommend you open it in a proper python IDE like PyCharm or Visual Studio Code so you can find issues.

### Voila they're back!

[image]

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much :)